# Laravel validation method not allowed

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm trying to set validation on my controller method, but on validation failure I'm getting error that method is not allowed http exception.

My controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Web;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Services\InvoicesService;

class InvoiceController extends Controller
{

private $invoice;

public function __construct(InvoicesService $invoice) {
    $this->invoice = $invoice;
}

public function startNewInvoice($id, $customer) 
{
    $ticket = $this->invoice->getTicketByInvoice($id);
    $ticket = $ticket->Ticket;
    return view('form', ['InvoiceId' => $id,'CustomerInfo' => $customer, 'records' => null, 'recordState' => null, 'ticket' => $ticket, 'invoices' => null]);
}

public function generateInvoice(Request $request)
{
    //dd($request);

    $this->validate($request, [
        'CustomerNumber' => 'required|numeric'
        ]);

    $invoiceId = $request->input('Invoice');
    $customer = array('CustomerCode' => $request->input('CustomerNumber'),'CustomerName' => $request->input('CustomerName'),'CustomerAddress' => $request->input('CustomerAddress'),
                      'CustomerVATCode' => $request->input('CustomerVatNumber'));

    $hash = $this->invoice->generateInvoice($invoiceId, $customer);

    $newInvoice = $this->invoice->newInvoice($request->input('CustomerNumber'), $hash->Id);

    return $this->startNewInvoice($newInvoice->Id, $customer);

}
```

}

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Does your blade view under `<form>` contain a `{{ method_field() }}? You should be using this for using HTTP verb of `PUT/PATCH` or `DELETE` https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-method-field

Comment: My <form> contains {{ csrf_field() }} because I'm using POST method. I don't why, but I'm getting 405 Method Not Allowed.

Comment: For methods other than `POST` and `GET`, you need to specify the exact method in the {{ method_field() }} helper. If you are doing that, the `method` in `<form>` has to be `POST`.